# Give an exact expression for the doubling time of the function y = 80 (1.4)^x/4, and quote an approximate numerical value.

Tags: numerical-calculus

Give an exact expression for the doubling time of the function y = 80 (1.4)^x/4, and quote an approximate
numerical value.

what I did:  y = 80 (1.4)^x/4

```
         y = 80 (1.4)^2/4
         y = 80 (1.4)^1/2
         y=56
```

is that the correct?

Comment: Parentheses, please.  You have written $\frac {80\cdot 1.4^x}4$ but I suspect you mean $80\cdot 1.4^{x/4}$.  Even better, use MathJax as suggested in the FAQ

Comment: I'd say, bigtudo, that what you have done is not even wrong. Doubling time is not a value of $y$, it's the difference between two values of $x$.

Comment: Are you trying to get a reputation for ignoring people's work on your questions, bigtudo?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I am not ignoring. I am new to this platform and I did not use this web site after I posted it.

Comment: Welcome back, bigtudo. If one of the answers has solved your problem, you can "accept" it by clicking in the check mark next to it.

Comment: Today would be a good day to do that, bigtudo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A naive way to do it is:

1. plug-in a value for $x$
2. compute for the corresponding $y$.
3. plug-in double the computed value of $y$
4. solve for the corresponding $x$ value for the doubled $y$
5. take the positive difference of the the solved value of $x$ and the first plugged-in value for $x$

Say for your question:

1. Plug-in $x=0$ into $y=80(1.4)^{\frac{x}{4}}$
2. We obtain $y=80$ since $80(1.4)^{\frac{0}{4}}=80$
3. Plug-in $y=160$ into $y=80(1.4)^{\frac{x}{4}}$
4. Solving for $x$ in $160=80(1.4)^{\frac{x}{4}}$ we obtain $x= 4 \log_{1.4} 2$
5. Getting the difference of the two $x$-values, we have the doubling time of $4 \log_{1.4} 2$

Comment: Thank you for the explanation for this question! I thought 2x instead of 80x2! Thank you so much ! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The doubling time is the difference in $x$ that doubles the value of $y$.  Pick a starting $y$.  You might just plug in $x=0$ and compute $y$.  Now find the $x$ which corresponds to $2y$.  The difference in the $x$'s is the doubling time.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!